# C# comparing two user inputs

Tags: c#

I want to compare two user inputs. So for example:

```
     if(userinput == "Yes" || "yes")

     {   //do whatever...       }
```

Not sure how to do this? as the above method doesn't work. New to c#

Comment: yea.. the question and the code don't really match.. do you have one user input and you want to compare it with two values or do you have two user inputs and you want to compare them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
if(userinput == "Yes" || "yes")
```

with

```
if(userinput == "Yes" || userinput ==  "yes")
```

or even better if you want to ignore case sensitivity completely

```
if (userinput.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read about [if statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) in MSDN:

```
if(userinput == "Yes" || userinput  =="yes") {}
```

You can also use:

```
string.Equals(userinput , "yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make generic solution with ignoring the case:

```
var userinput = "yEs";

if(userinput.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{ // do some work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get only one case doing the following:

```
        if (userinput.ToUpper() == "YES" )
        {
            do what you want
        }
```

ToUpper() method make all letters uppercase so you have the only "YES" case without handling any other case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to change the string inputed like this:

```
if(userinput.ToLower() == "yes")
{

}
```